# Is there a way to extract the svg layer from a Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

[Edit]

Hi everyone,

I have created a leaflet map using geojson data from [City of Chicago Data portal](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Ward-Precincts-2012-2022-/uvpq-qeeq).  I'm trying to extract the SVG polygons from this leaflet map. I don't want the base layer to show. All I want is the SVG polygons shapes. I've tried using the Chrome developer inspect tools and I am able to see the SVG group. I tried to copy and paste the SVG paths into another HTML file. But nothing renders. I was hoping to use [SVG Crowbar](https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) But that can only be used for svgs created by d3.js.

[image: leaflet map of Chicago]

[image: leaflet map with SVG inspector]

Comment: Why not find out where the polies came from and use that directly?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. Can you please elaborate? I have the geojson data. When I inspect the page I see the SVG paths. They just won't render in another index.html file

Comment: Ah: in that case please update your post to [include those details](/help/how-to-ask). Explain what you set out to do, and talk about the data you have and code you tried writing, so that folks are up to speed on where you're at right now, and how to get unblocked. And of course, converting geojson to SVG is not a trick exclusive to Leaflet, so just searching SO or the web for how to convert geojson to SVG will find you a bunch of results as well: did none of those help?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Mike. I'm going to edit my question a bit more. I'll try to do more research on converting geojson to SVG. But will that work for a more complicated map like choropleth map.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your time and thank you for helping me. I was able to find a solution. There is another google chrome extension svg gobbler that did the trick.   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-gobbler/mpbmflcodadhgafbbakjeahpandgcbch

Comment: Sounds like you solved your own problem in about 10 minutes, probably worth deleting this question again =)